# Difference Max and Min from Different Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, max, min

I'm going to try to explain this the best I can.

The code below does the following:

- Finds a service address from the ServiceLocation table.
- Finds a service type (electric or water).
- Finds how many days in the past to pull data.

Once it has this, it calculates the "daily usage" by subtracting the max meter read for a day from the minimum meter read for a day.

```
        (MAX(mr.Reading) - MIN(mr.Reading)) AS 'DaytimeUsage'
```

However, what I'm missing is the max reading from the day prior and the minimum reading from the current day. Mathematically, this should look something like this:

- MAX(PriorDayReading) - MIN(ReadDateReading)

Essentially, if it goes back 5 days it should kick out a table that reads as follows:

> ### Service Location |  Read Date |  Usage |
>
> 123 Main St      | 4/20/15    |  12    |
>   123 Main St      | 4/19/15    |  8     |
>   123 Main St      | 4/18/15    |  6     |
>   123 Main St      | 4/17/15    |  10    |
>   123 Main St      | 4/16/15    |  11    |

Where "Usage" is the 'DaytimeUsage' + usage that I'm missing (and the question above). For example, 4/18/15 would be the 'DaytimeUsage' in the query below PLUS the the difference between the MAX read from 4/17/15 and the MIN read from 4/18/15.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this or if it is possible.

```
SELECT 
    A.ServiceAddress AS 'Service Address', 
    convert(VARCHAR(10),A.ReadDate,101) AS 'Date', 
    SUM(A.[DaytimeUsage]) AS 'Usage' 

FROM 
(
    SELECT
        sl.location_addr AS 'ServiceAddress', 
        convert(VARCHAR(10),mr.read_date,101) AS 'ReadDate', 
        (MAX(mr.Reading) - MIN(mr.Reading)) AS 'DaytimeUsage'
    FROM
        DimServiceLocation AS sl
        INNER JOIN FactBill AS fb ON fb.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
        INNER JOIN FactMeterRead as mr ON mr.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
        INNER JOIN DimCustomer AS c ON c.CustomerKey = fb.CustomerKey
    WHERE 
        c.class_name = 'Tenant'
        AND sl.ServiceLocationKey = @ServiceLocation
        AND mr.meter_type = @ServiceType
    GROUP BY 
        sl.location_addr, 
        convert(VARCHAR(10),
        mr.read_date,101)
) A

WHERE A.ReadDate >= GETDATE()-@Days 
GROUP BY A.ServiceAddress, convert(VARCHAR(10),A.ReadDate,101)
ORDER BY convert(VARCHAR(10),A.ReadDate,101) DESC
```

Comment: all i understand is you want to get the max read for yesterday and min read for today.. This can be achieved with date between function

Comment: Yes. However, it needs to do it for each date within the date range. So, the difference between the max read for 4/16 and min read for 4/17 then the difference between the max read for 4/17 and the min read for 4/16... etc. 

Adding those sums to the existing MIN and MAX read difference for each read date in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the APPLY operator if you are above sql server 2005.  Here is a link to the documentation.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx  The APPLY operation comes in two forms OUTER APPLY AND CROSS APPLY - OUTER works like a left join and CROSS works like an inner join.  They let you run a query once for each row returned.  I setup my own sample of what you were trying to do, here it is and I hope it helps.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdb3f/1

```
CREATE TABLE SequencedValues (
  Location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  CalendarDate datetime NOT NULL,
  Reading int
  )

INSERT INTO SequencedValues (
  Location,
  CalendarDate,
  Reading
  )
 SELECT
   'Address1',
   '4/20/2015',
   10
UNION SELECT
   'Address1',
   '4/19/2015',
   9
UNION SELECT
   'Address1',
   '4/19/2015',
   20
UNION SELECT
   'Address1',
   '4/19/2015',
   25
UNION SELECT
   'Address1',
   '4/18/2015',
   8
UNION SELECT
   'Address1',
   '4/17/2015',
   7
UNION SELECT
   'Address2',
   '4/20/2015',
   100
UNION SELECT
   'Address2',
   '4/20/2015',
   111
UNION SELECT
   'Address2',
   '4/19/2015',
   50
UNION SELECT
   'Address2',
   '4/19/2015',
   65


SELECT DISTINCT 
    sv.Location,
    sv.CalendarDate,
    sv_dayof.MINDayOfReading,
    sv_daybefore.MAXDayBeforeReading
FROM SequencedValues sv
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MIN(sv_dayof_inside.Reading) AS MINDayOfReading
    FROM SequencedValues sv_dayof_inside
    WHERE sv.Location = sv_dayof_inside.Location
    AND sv.CalendarDate = sv_dayof_inside.CalendarDate
    ) sv_dayof
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(sv_daybefore_max.Reading) AS MAXDayBeforeReading
    FROM SequencedValues sv_daybefore_max
    WHERE sv.Location = sv_daybefore_max.Location
    AND sv_daybefore_max.CalendarDate IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 sv_daybefore_inside.CalendarDate
        FROM SequencedValues sv_daybefore_inside
        WHERE sv.Location = sv_daybefore_inside.Location
        AND sv.CalendarDate > sv_daybefore_inside.CalendarDate
        ORDER BY sv_daybefore_inside.CalendarDate DESC
        )
    ) sv_daybefore
ORDER BY
    sv.Location,
    sv.CalendarDate DESC
```

Comment: With a few tweaks to account for multiple reads per day, this worked like a charm! Thanks!

I still need to verify that it accounts for days that don't have any reads, if you have suggestions as to how to handle that let me know. Basically, go back to the last available max read (if it happened on any day other than the day prior). 

If I'm correct, the SELECT TOP 1 should handle this, no?

Comment: @johnwonderbread you are correct.  If you want to say go back to the prior date regardless of if it is the day before or not, this will work fine because of the TOP 1 and the ORDER BY.  If however you want just the prior day you need to either do a DATEADD -1 or create a separate table called Calendar that for each date has the previous date, previous business date, whatever other meta information you need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could solve this by just calculating the difference between the MAX of yesterday & today, however this is how I would approach it. Join to the same table again for the previous day relative to any given day, and select the Max/Min for that too within your inner query. Also if you place the date in the inner query where clause the data set you return will be quicker & smaller.

```
SELECT 
A.ServiceAddress AS 'Service Address', 
  convert(VARCHAR(10),A.ReadDate,101) AS 'Date', 
  SUM(A.[TodayMax]) - SUM(A.[TodayMin]) AS 'Usage',
  SUM(A.[TodayMax]) - SUM(A.[YesterdayMax]) AS 'Usage with extra bit you want' 
FROM 
(
SELECT
    sl.location_addr AS 'ServiceAddress', 
    convert(VARCHAR(10),mr.read_date,101) AS 'ReadDate', 
    MAX(mrT.Reading) AS 'TodayMax',
    MIN(mrT.Reading) AS 'TodayMin',
    MAX(mrY.Reading) AS 'YesterdayMax',
    MIN(mrY.Reading) AS 'YesterdayMin',        
FROM
    DimServiceLocation AS sl
    INNER JOIN FactBill AS fb ON fb.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
    INNER JOIN FactMeterRead as mrT ON mrT.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
    INNER JOIN FactMeterRead as mrY ON mrY.ServiceLocationKey = s1.ServiceLocationKey
                                    AND mrY.read_date = mrT.read_date -1)
    INNER JOIN DimCustomer AS c ON c.CustomerKey = fb.CustomerKey
WHERE 
    c.class_name = 'Tenant'
    AND sl.ServiceLocationKey = @ServiceLocation
    AND mr.meter_type = @ServiceType
    AND convert(VARCHAR(10), mrT.read_date,101) >= GETDATE()-@Days 
GROUP BY 
    sl.location_addr, 
    convert(VARCHAR(10),
    mr.read_date,101)

) A
GROUP BY A.ServiceAddress, convert(VARCHAR(10),A.ReadDate,101)
ORDER BY convert(VARCHAR(10),A.ReadDate,101) DESC
```

Comment: When running this on an actual data set, each read_date (4/20/15, 4/19/15, 4/18/15, etc) has the same usage for each column (usage & usage with extra bit).

They all seem to be the most recent day, instead of accurate to the read date. 

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you run the internal query and see if there is a difference for the given dates between the min for today and the max for yesterday? Perhaps there is no missing data.

Comment: Yeah, I expanded it back to 30 days and checked against actual read data. Unfortunately, it returns the same result for each row instead of calculating each row against that row's read date.

Comment: Does each row have the same result for all 30 days, or do you mean that the today & yesterday values are the same for any given day?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I full understood your db structure but I may have a solution so feel free to edit my answer to adapt or correct any mistake.

The idea is to use two aliases for the table FactMeterRead. mrY (Y as yesterday) and mrT (T as Today). And differentiate them with a read_date restriction.
However I didn't understand enough your tables to write a fully functional query. I hope you will get the idea anyway with this example.

```
SELECT
        sl.location_addr AS 'ServiceAddress', 
        convert(VARCHAR(10),mrT.read_date,101) AS 'ReadDate', 
        (MAX(mrY.Reading) - MIN(mrT.Reading)) AS 'DaytimeUsage'
    FROM
        DimServiceLocation AS sl
          INNER JOIN FactMeterRead as mrY ON mrY.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
          INNER JOIN FactMeterRead as mrT ON mrT.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
    WHERE mrY.read_date=DATE_SUB(mrT.read_date,1 DAY)
```